# How to print details of a 'catch all' exception in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm updating my code to use Swift, and I'm wondering how to print error details for an exception that matches the 'catch all' clause.  I've slightly modified the example from this [Swift Language Guide Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) to illustrate my point:

```
do {
    try vend(itemNamed: "Candy Bar")
    // Enjoy delicious snack
} catch VendingMachineError.InvalidSelection {
    print("Invalid Selection.")
} catch VendingMachineError.OutOfStock {
    print("Out of Stock.")
} catch VendingMachineError.InsufficientFunds(let amountRequired) {
    print("Insufficient funds. Please insert an additional $\(amountRequired).")
} catch {
    // HOW DO I PRINT OUT INFORMATION ABOUT THE ERROR HERE?
}
```

If I catch an unexpected exception, I need to be able to log something about what caused it.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

I just figured it out.  I noticed this line in the Swift Documentation:

> If a catch clause does not specify a pattern, the clause will match and bind any error to a local constant named error

So, then I tried this:

```
do {
    try vend(itemNamed: "Candy Bar")
...
} catch {
    print("Error info: \(error)")
}
```

And it gave me a nice description.

Comment: i really appreciated the nice error message that this print you suggested gave me : +1 for the this my friend

Answer (score 56):

From *The Swift Programming Language*:

> If a `catch` clause does not specify a pattern, the clause will match and bind any error to a local constant named `error`.

That is, there is an implicit `let error` in the `catch` clause:

```
do {
    // …
} catch {
    print("caught: \(error)")
}
```

Alternatively, it seems that `let constant_name` is also a valid pattern, so you could use it to rename the error constant (this might conceivably be handy if the name `error` is already in use):

```
do {
    // …
} catch let myError {
   print("caught: \(myError)")
}
```